# Send data by post by row id from foreach loop(Opencart 3)

Tags: javascript

I have table which is generation by foreach loop( in opencart 3 it is for loop(symphony syntax)). I have edit button for each row and open modal with realted info by row_id. But on form submit by ajax it does not takes choosen row id and takes last row_id.(i am sending by hidden input, but nor working) How can I send choosen ID and do update by require id? here is my code

```js
$(document).on('click', '#saveeditedrule', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var action = $(this).data('action');
  var rule_id = $('#rule_id').val();

  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: action,
    cache: false,
    data: {
      'credit_rule_id': rule_id
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
      console.log('Start...');

    },
    complete: function() {
      $('#saveeditedrule').button('reset');
    },
    success: function(data) {
      alert(rule_id);
      console.log('done');

    },
    error: function() {
      console.log('something is wrong');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="examples" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>column1</th>
      <th>column 2</th>
      <th width="80px">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for rules in credittules %}
    <tr>

      <td>Something</td>
      <td>Something 2</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal{{ rules.credit_rule_id }}">Edit</button>
      </td>

      <!-- here is my modal--->
      <div class="modal fade" id="editModal{{ rules.credit_rule_id }}" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <form id="form-rule" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Title</h4>
              </div>

              <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="hidden" name="rule_id" id="rule_id" value="{{ rules.credit_rule_id }}" />

              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-left" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteconfirm" data-loading-text="{{ text_loading }}">{{ text_sil }}</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-target="#editconfirm" data-loading-text="{{ text_loading }}"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{ text_edit }}</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">{{ text_no }}</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="modal fade" id="deleteconfirm" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <p style="text-align:center;">{{ text_confirm_delete }}</p>
              <hr />
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">{{ text_no }}</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right" data-action="{{ action_delete_rule }}" data-dismiss="modal" id="deleteeditedrule">{{ text_yes }}</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal fade" id="editconfirm" role="dialog" style="z-index: 1051;">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <p style="text-align:center;">{{ text_confirm_edit }}</p>
              <hr /> {{ rules.credit_rule_id }}
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">{{ text_no }}</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right" data-action="{{ action_rule }}" data-dismiss="modal" id="saveeditedrule">{{ text_yes }}</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </tr>

    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thats because u have multiple buttons with the same id `saveeditedrule`... `ID`'s have to be unique

Comment: @DarkBee thank you for reply. I did it, but still getting same last id.how to pass to ajax that row id?

Comment: You still have to target the correct input now... See my answer for an "easier" aproach on this

Comment: If you wanted to target it, it would be something like `$('input[type="hidden"], $(this).parent().prev()).val()`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of working with hidden inputs it is nowadays much easier to use a `data` attribute actually

`twig`

```
{% for rules in credittules %}
    ...
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success pull-right" data-action="{{ action_delete_rule }}" data-rule-id="{{ rules.credit_rule_id }}" data-dismiss="modal" id="deleteeditedrule">{{ text_yes }}</button>
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

*javascript*

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'button[data-rule-id]', function() {

          var action = $(this).data('action');
          var rule_id = $(this).data('rule-id');

          $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: action,
            cache: false,
            data: {
              'credit_rule_id': rule_id
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
              console.log('Start...');

            },
            complete: function() {
              $('#saveeditedrule').button('reset');
            },
            success: function(data) {
              alert(rule_id);
              console.log('done');

            },
            error: function() {
              console.log('something is wrong');
            }
          });       
    });
});
```

Comment: so, if i have multiple input i should add `data-mycolumn="{{ rules.mycolumn }}"` and in js should ` var mycolumn= $(this).data('mycolumn');` . I will try now

Comment: here is fiddle of my code. http://jsfiddle.net/oa4rLzvp/#
 I can do it by submit button, but want to know the way by ajax.

Comment: It sends data by id, but send it empty. Still can not target inputs (